# How do I skip first row of Excel in order to upload into my database

Tags: php, excel

I'm still at the first stage of learning. Here is my problem: I want to skip the first row of an Excel file to upload it into the database. I hope you can help me to solve this.

Here is the code:

```
    $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);


    $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
    for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
    {

        $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);


        foreach ($Reader as $Row)
        {


            $period = "";
            if(isset($Row[0])) {
                $period = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[0]);
            }

            $target = "";
            if(isset($Row[1])) {
                $target = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[1]);
            }

            $achieved = "";
            if(isset($Row[2])) {
                $achieved = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[2]);
            }

            $batch = "";
```

Comment: It looks as though the code has been cut off? The loops don't close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `continue` to skip processing for just the first row.

```
foreach ($Reader as $index => $Row) {
    if ($index === 0) {
        continue;
    }

    // process $Row
}
```

This assumes `$Reader` has a zero-based index.